# Using tkinter module nothing is happening

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am relatively new to python, and i have this program that runs without errors without doing anything.

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
btn = Button(tk, text="click me")
btn.pack()
```

it runs without errors and then in the idle shell it just shows the next prompt (>>>) without doing anything. Oh, by the way i am using python 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most GUI frameworks need you to enter the gui mainloop to have anything happening.

Try adding a mainloop call at the end:

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk() 
btn = Button(tk, text="click me")
btn.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Maybe have a look at the tutorial at http://www.tkdocs.com